# Prevent for loop to print out duplicates of content if counter hasn't reached last of index

Tags: c#

This is probably a brainfart from start, my apologies. I understand the way the *for loop* work printing out content on each iteration. But is there a way to print out the content on a fulfilled condition only when the counter has reached last of index?

I just can't wrap my head around this when combined with if conditions, I might overthink a simple task and have the wrong approach in mind.

I had something like this in mind at first. Which of course not always is true when last of index is reached:
`(numbers[i] == randomNums[j] && i+1 == numbers.Length)`

Any ideas?

**The for loop used:**

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < randomNums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == randomNums[j]) 
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                        Console.WriteLine("############## B I N G O ##############");
                        Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Better luck next time!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: unclear what's your goal. you're comparing elements of `numbers` and `randomNums` one by one? when should `bingo` get printed?

Comment: Last loop would occur when `i == numbers.Length - 1 && j == randomNums.Length - 1`.

Comment: It's not clear why you're printing _anything_ on each iteration.  "is there a way to print out the content on a fulfilled condition only when the counter has reached last of index?" - When the last index is reached, the loop is over, so just put that code _after_ the loop.    Count the matches within the loop, then after the loop is when you'd display the final result.

Comment: You're right about that! Have made some adjustments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
    private static void CheckBingo(int[] numbers, int[] randomNums)
    {
        var intersect = numbers.Intersect(randomNums).Count();
        var mess = intersect > 0 ? "BINGO" : "Better luck next time!";            

        Console.WriteLine(mess);
    }
```

OR

```
    private static void CheckBingo(int[] numbers, int[] randomNums)
    {
        var hasMatch = numbers.Any(x => randomNums.Contains(x));
        var mess = hasMatch? "BINGO" : "Better luck next time!";            
        Console.WriteLine(mess);
    }
```

You will need to add the reference:

```
using System.Linq;
```

---

**EDIT**
If you wish to keep the looping format you could just do this:

```
    private static void CheckBingo(int[] numbers, int[] randomNums)
    {
        foreach (var n in numbers)
        {
            foreach (var r in randomNums)
            {
                if (n == r)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                    Console.WriteLine("############## B I N G O ##############");
                    Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Better luck next time!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var numbers = new int[] {1,2,8,7,69};
        var randomNums = new int[] {2,3,5,76,4,42};
        var firstLoopEnd = false;
        var secondLoopEnd = false;
        var lastNumFromNum = 0;
        var lastNumFromRnd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers.Length - 1 == i)
            {
                firstLoopEnd = true;
                lastNumFromNum = numbers[i];
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < randomNums.Length; j++)
            {               
                if (randomNums.Length - 1 == j) 
                {
                    secondLoopEnd = true;
                    lastNumFromRnd = randomNums[j];
                }
            }

            if (firstLoopEnd && secondLoopEnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                Console.WriteLine("############## B I N G O ##############");
                Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
                Console.WriteLine("Last number from 'numbers': " + lastNumFromNum + ", Last number from 'randomNums': " + lastNumFromRnd);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Better luck next time!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to know when each loop finishes.

Tested on .NET Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcP6FM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies!

I found a solution of what I was looking for, setting a bool variable and put an if outside to prevent the Bingo message from printing out multiple times:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < randomNums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == randomNums[j]) 
                {
                    winner = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (winner == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
            Console.WriteLine("############## B I N G O ##############");
            Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Inga rätt här, bättre lycka nästa gång!");
        }
```

Comment: Won't numbers[i] == randomNums[j] compare the actual numbers? I thought you wanted to know what both arrays were at their last index, which is different from the value of each element in a particular iteration. Unless I misunderstood.